# Loading bootstrap selectpicker in angular2

Tags: angular, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am trying to use bootstrap selectpicker in my angular2 application. I have loaded jquery and bootstrap-select scripts in angular-cli.json.

This is my app-component.ts

```
 import $ from 'jquery';
  ngOnInit() {
   $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
  }
```

But, I am getting this error.

__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_jquery___default(...)(...).selectpicker is not a function.

I am new to angular2. Please help!

Comment: you still requires the bootstrap.js for bootstrap's selectpicker

Comment: "styles": [
          "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
          "../node_modules/typeface-montserrat/index.css",
          "../node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],     
      "scripts": ["../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
      "../node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"

      ]

Comment: I have inluded all these files in angular-cli.json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my Solution,

Open ***typings.d.ts*** file in angular-cli and add the following lines

```js
interface JQuery {
   addClass(className: string): JQuery;
   attr(attributeName: string, value: string|number): JQuery;
}
interface JQuery {
     selectpicker(options?: any, callback?: Function):any;
}
```

Don't import jquery instead:

```
declare var $:any;
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. But could you please explain what actually is happening here?